# How can I change the line height in iTerm2?

Tags: terminal, iterm2, iterm

I've tried looking through iTerm2's text preferences, but I don't see a way to change line height.

How can I add more space between lines in iTerm2 for Mac?

Answer (score 6):

You can go to:
Preferences -> Profiles tab -> Text -> In the **Font** row, the line height value should be the last one.

Comment: Thanks! Great way to fix Powerline character misalignment!